rm command works in shell but not in Makefile
I have an rm command that does not work in a Makefile but when I copy it to the shell it works:
$ make clean
rm paper.{abs,blg,pdf,aux,log,bbl,out,xmpdata}
rm: cannot remove 'paper.{abs,blg,pdf,aux,log,bbl,out,xmpdata}': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:8: clean] Error 1
$ rm paper.{abs,blg,pdf,aux,log,bbl,out,xmpdata}
$

What can cause this? The file rights seem to be OK. I tried using double quotes and apostrophes around the filename expression but neither worked.
UPDATE: I run GNU Make 4.3 on Ubuntu 22.04

GNU Make runs the POSIX-compliant /bin/sh for a shell.  It would be a disaster for portability if it invoked whatever shell the user was using.
The {} form you're using is not a POSIX-conforming syntax: POSIX does not define any special behavior for {}.  You are trying to take advantage of a capability of your personal shell (likely bash) which is non-standard.
You either need to write out the multiple filenames or use standard POSIX globbing, or else add a line to your makefile to force it to use bash instead of /bin/sh, like:
SHELL := /bin/bash

Note then your makefile will not work properly on any system where /bin/bash is not present.
You could also use a GNU Make function, such as:
clean:
        rm $(addprefix paper.,abs,blg,pdf,aux,log,bbl,out,xmpdata)


Thanks. Only another person will use this makefile.

see my answer to do it without using bash

Following this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270799/46710
I was able to do this within classic shell:
define clean_aux_files =

        for e in abs blg pdf aux log bbl out xmpdata
        do 
          rm "paper.$e"
        done
endef

.ONESHELL:

clean:  
        $(value clean_aux_files)
        rm pdfa.xmpi texput.log

I tested this and it worked.

I mean, OK, but this seems a LOT more complicated and hard to understand than just writing rm paper.abs paper.blg paper.pdf paper.aux paper.log paper.bbl paper.out paper.xpmdata.  Or, using the addprefix GNU Make function as I suggested in my answer.

Obviously, paper is replaced by a longer file name

Nevertheless, the addprefix function is almost the same as the original {...} version and much simpler than switching on .ONESHELL and writing a separate variable with a for loop.  IMO.
